# How to deploy SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created integration catalog in sql server. 
But i was not able to create folder in integration catalog for SSISDB

Getting error like:

> Create on object named SSISDB, folder creation failed executing.

I have set permissions: Trustworthy on for ssisdb, but it has not worked.

Comment: Which versions are you using?

Comment: Based on the question's title and the message, I am unable to determine where the problem is coming from. Generally, once the SSISDB is created, you will add sub-folders to it for project groupings. From there, I deploy from either Visual Studio (i.e., in development) or ISDeploymentWizard.exe (i.e., in production). Did you follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-2017? If not, I need for you to be more specific as to when you are getting the error.

Comment: In SSMS, run the following and report back on any errors `EXECUTE SSISDB.catalog.create_folder @folder_name=N'MyFolder'`